# How do I filter in supabase if an item of a column array is included in another array?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

how are you? Im trying to filter all the posts that has a tag included in the tags that the user follows. I have two supabase tables: user and post. The nextjs api route goes like this:

```
  const {
    tags,
    limit,
    following,
  }: {
    tags: string[] | null;
    limit: number;
    following: string[] | null;
  } = req.body;

  if ((!tags || tags.length === 0) && (!following || following.length === 0)) {
    res.status(200).json({ posts: [] });
  }

  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published, id, tags, created_by!inner( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .or(`tags.cs.${tags || []}, created_by.id.in.${following || []}`)
    .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
    .limit(limit);

  if (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ posts: data });
```

The created_by filter works fine, but the first `or`, doesn't. it throws this error: "failed to parse logic tree ((tags.cs.mithology"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement an 'or' operator in supabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519892/how-to-implement-an-or-operator-in-supabase)