# How to implement an 'or' operator in supabase

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase, supabase-database

How are you? I'm having trouble implementing the `or` operator in supabase.

I need to create a 'for you' tab, so I'm trying to filter the posts depending on the tags and people the user follows.

When I implement the `in` and `contains` operators separately, it works fine. But when I implement the `or` operator, it fails. Also, I've tried doing `` .or(`tags.contains.${tags || []}, created_by.id.in.${following || []}`) `` also

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published, id, tags, created_by!inner( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .contains("tags", tags || [])
    .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
    .limit(limit);
```

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published, id, tags, created_by!inner( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .in('created_by.id', following || [])
    .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
    .limit(limit);
```

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published, id, tags, created_by!inner( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .or(`tags.cn.${tags || []}, created_by.id.in.${following || []}`)
    .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
    .limit(limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

`or` filter expects the raw postgREST syntax, which makes it a bit unique to work with. For `contains`, the array has to be wrapped in `{}`, and for `in`, the array has to be wrapped in `()`.

Also, `contains` filter is `cs`, and not `cn`.

So you would want something like this at the end:

```js
.or(`tags.cs.{"tag1", "tag2"}, created_by.id.in.("id1", "id2")`)
```

You can read more about it on the official docs here
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/or?example=use-or-on-referenced-tables